# Spring Cloud Gateway server not starting up with Spring Cloud 2023.0.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to create Spring Cloud Gateway server. But when server is getting started getting below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'gatewayCompositeRouterFunction': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'gatewayRouterFunctionHolder' defined in BeanDefinition defined in null: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.config.GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar$RouterFunctionHolder: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class
```

**Spring boot version 3.2.0
spring-cloud.version 2023.0.0
java.version 17**

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=gateway-server
server.port=9090


# Eureka config
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
```

Comment: Please show your dependencies and java configuration

Comment: Seems to be a regression bug. There is a related GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/3199

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc` conflicts with `spring-boot-devtools`

Just try remove `spring-boot-devtools`, hope it could help

Answer (score 1):

Try changing dependency in your POM from 'gateway-mvc' to 'gateway';

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to below;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a class modifier error to me. Go to the below class and check whether it is final or not. If you have declared it final then remove the final keyword as Spring proxying process requires the class to be not-final. It needs to be visible too.

```
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.config.GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar$RouterFunctionHolder
```

Comment: This class is from Spring Framework I cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest releases, spring has changed the artifact id from
spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc to spring-cloud-starter-gateway.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove "spring-boot-devtools" and Re-Start the Application.,i hope it works fine